# Pandas: How to find indexes of values between a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with a series of numbers in the column 'Num'.

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = np.array([10,15,60,45,37,28])
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers, columns= ['Num'])
```

I would find all the combinations of the indexes of values that satisfy the condition:

```
numbers1+numbers2+... >= 70% of df['Num'].sum()
```

`df['Num'].sum() = 195`, so 136.5 is the 70%. Some combninations of values could be:

```
10+15+60 
15+60 
60+45+37
10+15+60+45+37+28
```

and so on. I would take the indexes combinations and, at the end, get the combination(/s) that's over 70% with the lowest number of indexes.

Comment: What is the reason for a pandas dataframe here?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta this is just a sample code. I'm working on a bigger DataFrame.

Comment: The bigger it is, the less I would use pandas for such a requirement!

Comment: I started with pandas few weeks ago and coding is a hobby. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools` here:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([10,15,60,45,37,28])
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers, columns= ['Num'])
total = int(df.sum())
list_n = list(df['Num'])
for L in range(0, len(list_n)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(list_n, L):
        if sum(subset) > 0.7 * total:
            print(subset)

(60, 45, 37)
(10, 60, 45, 37)
(10, 60, 45, 28)
(15, 60, 45, 37)
(15, 60, 45, 28)
(15, 60, 37, 28)
(60, 45, 37, 28)
(10, 15, 60, 45, 37)
(10, 15, 60, 45, 28)
(10, 15, 60, 37, 28)
(10, 60, 45, 37, 28)
(15, 60, 45, 37, 28)
(10, 15, 60, 45, 37, 28)
```

Of course you could skip pandas altogether:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([10,15,60,45,37,28])
total = sum(numbers)
for L in range(0, len(numbers)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(numbers, L):
        if sum(subset) > 0.7 * total:
            print(subset)

(60, 45, 37)
(10, 60, 45, 37)
(10, 60, 45, 28)
(15, 60, 45, 37)
(15, 60, 45, 28)
(15, 60, 37, 28)
(60, 45, 37, 28)
(10, 15, 60, 45, 37)
(10, 15, 60, 45, 28)
(10, 15, 60, 37, 28)
(10, 60, 45, 37, 28)
(15, 60, 45, 37, 28)
(10, 15, 60, 45, 37, 28)
```

Comment: Thank you so much NYC Coder. Now I'll try to get the indexes. Have a great Week end!